# Cant login to onedrive with microsoft buisniss account

Tags: windows, onedrive

I opened a free trial of windows for buisness account, Im trying to login to my onedrive account but I get this:

[image]

And after a few minutes I'm getting this:

[image]

If I ry from desktop app I get error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6NdQi.png)

any suggestions?

Comment: So, the issue appears to be one of patience… how long did you wait?

Comment: something like 3 minutes, but I tried also yesturday, and it was the same

Comment: Have you tried to uninstall OneDrive, reboot PC and reinstall it? Here is the [download link](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=844652).

Comment: @EmilyHua I tried to login from browser, I added pic of my attempt via desktop app

Comment: I find a thread about error code **0x8004deed**, [onedrive issue](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_drive-mso_win10-msoversion_other/onedrive-issue/b2a9bd53-45d4-478b-be22-40630c2a0102?page=1), maybe you could have a look